# How to recognize linear transformations and projections from matrix operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, affine-geometry, projection-matrices

I have an object
$$
C =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where the first row contains x-coordinates for the vertices, the second row contains y-coordinates for the vertices, and the third row contains z-coordinates for the vertices.

I have a matrix operator
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2/5 & -1/5 & -1/5 \\
-1/5 & -2/5 & 3/5 \\
-1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I have already plotted the object C with the transformed object AC, along with the eigenvectors of A [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVCQw.jpg).

[image]

It looks like A projects C along one eigenvector onto a plane formed by the other two eigenvectors, and also does some reflection/rotation (?) [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Cnh5.jpg).

[image]

My questions is this:

> By looking at $A$, or its eigenvalues and eigenvectors, how can I
>   recognize what $A$ will do to $C$? I.e. that it is in fact a projection
>   operator? What features in $A$ determine where the object gets projected
>   onto, gets rotated to, gets translated to ... etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Feeding your $A$ into Octave yields:

```
>> A
A =

   0.40000  -0.20000  -0.20000
  -0.20000  -0.40000   0.60000
  -1.00000   1.00000   0.00000
```

Then determining eigenvectors and values:

```
>> [B,C] = eig(A)
B =

  -4.0825e-001  5.7735e-001  5.2453e-017
  4.0825e-001  5.7735e-001  -7.0711e-001
  8.1650e-001  5.7735e-001  7.0711e-001

C =

Diagonal Matrix

  1.0000e+000            0            0
            0  -1.9429e-016            0
            0            0  -1.0000e+000
```

shows (second eigenvector to eigenvalue zero) that for your $A$ we have
$$
A \, (1,1,1)^\top = 0
$$

So if you use a coordinate system with one axis along $(1,1,1)^\top$,
then $A$ will zero the component in that direction.

$A$ is not a projection, because $A^2 \ne A$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, and for re-formatting my question. I understand your reply, and I got the same results (as far as eigenvalues and eigenvectors), but from the second image I posted, it looks like the image AC is on a plane that is in fact **not** perpendicular to (1,1,1)^\top. Moreover, I don't have any intuition for looking at A and understanding even roughly what A will do to C, which is what I'm hoping someone can help me with.

Comment: That statement was wrong. If you move to an orthonormal basis with $(1,1,1)^\top/\sqrt{3}$ as one of the basis vectors, then all the extensions of the object in that direction get flattened. I will have another look at this evening.

Comment: Thanks. The eigenvector/eigenvalue pair of (1,1,1) and 0 makes sense and is quite plain to understand that the object will get flattened in the direction of (1,1,1), as you say so nicely put @mvw. However, the other eigenvector/eigenvalue pairs; (i.e. pair 2: (-0.5 0.5 1) and 1; and pair 3: (0 -1 1) and -1) don't lend themselves so easily to comprehension.